# Why does scala return a Any(Val/Ref) when the function is obviously called with wrong types

Tags: scala, generics, types

I have this function:

```
def unpack[T] = (x:Option[T], y:T) => x match { case Some(z) => z; case None => y }
```

when I call it like this:

```
unpack(Some(1), 2)
```

the result is as expected:

```
res5: Int = 1
```

But when I call it with something clearly wrong:

```
unpack(Some("1"), 2)
```

the result is:

```
res6: Any = 1
```

I understand it can't infer the resulting type and it returns an `AnyRef/Val`.

But why doesn't it throw an error I clearly specified in the function that both the `Option` and the default are of type `T`.

Also the function definition clearly states that the result will be of type `T`:

```
unpack: [T]=> (Option[T], T) => T
```

Comment: Lets not discuss if this is good scala or not I understand there are probably far more elegant ways of doing this :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is Scala type inference at work. In the given example, it tries to find the common supertype of `String` and `Int` and that is `Any`

Consider a deeper type hierarchy:

```
trait Veggy
object tomato extends Veggy
trait Fruit extends Veggy
trait Orange extends Fruit
trait BloodOrange extends Orange
trait Apple extends Fruit
```

Then

```
unpack(Some(tomato), new Orange{}) // Veggy
unpack(Some(new Apple{}), new Orange{}) // Fruit
unpack(Some(new BloodOrange{}), new Orange{}) // Orange
```

Do you want to ensure that both parameters are of the exact same type? Then you need to tell the compiler that.

One possible way is to say that `x` and `y` each have a type and that there should be evidence that the two types are the same:

```
def unpack[T,U <:T ](x:Option[T], y:U)(implicit ev: T =:= U) : T = x match { case Some(z) => z; case None => y }

unpack(Some(new Fruit{}), new Orange{})
<console>:12: error: Cannot prove that Fruit =:= Orange.

unpack(Some(1), 2)  // Int = 1
```

Comment: Alright :) dude, this is probably why [f#] doesn't do automatic upcasting. Can you explain the type annotation a bit? What does `U <: T` mean. and what does the `implicit` arg do?

Comment: `U <: T` means that `U` must be a subtype of `T`. The `implicit` argument is used in this case to gather evidence that there's an equality relation between `T` and `U`. Further read: https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html